# Remove some paragraphs from html string

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string which is a sequence of html paragraphs, I want to remove (using String's method replaceAll) paragraphs which contain the word "UPDATE", usually they are in this form:

```
<p><a href="blabla">(UPDATE)<a></p>
```

but there could be other, as for example some strong section.
As it's almost impossible that a normal paragraph contain the exact word "UPDATE" I'd like just to find a regex which can find a paragraph which contains this word and remove it with

```
replaceAll("regex","");
```

can you help me  to find "regex" part?I'm not good at all with regex...

Comment: Strongly discourage regex and recommend a lightweight HTML parser like tagsoup to do this.

Comment: it is for an android app, as I just have those kind strings you think it's still better to add an external .jar file? I'm more worried about performances though...if you say me that I'll get an improvement I could try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. You need to use the .*? instead of .* because that forces the search to be lazy instead of greedy.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String haystack = "<p><a href='bla'>(UPDATE)</a></p><p><a href='bla'><strong>(UPDATE)</strong></a></p><p><a href='bla'><strong>(Non uppercase 'update' to show this match is exact)</strong></a></p><p><a href='bla'><strong>This does not contain the word you're looking for</strong></a></p>";
        String regex = "<p>.*?(UPDATE).*?</p>";

        String result = haystack.replaceAll(regex, "");
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where is the exact difference?Is it more efficient?

Comment: @Phate Jeroen regex is better because if you have 2 paragraphs one after the other, it will find both. +1 for Jeroen, I delete mine.